# Swift static library

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to create a utility project that is shared between my company's iOS apps. I've done this at a previous job, but that predated Swift. I would obviously like to keep all of the implementation in swift, not Obj-C.

I tried the cocoapod route, using [this guide](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/06/25/developing-private-in-house-libraries-with-cocoapods/), but there are build issues there before I can even start using my utility code in the main project.

I'm now trying with just a 'Cocoa Touch Static Library' whose language is Swift, and still no luck. I imported the entire `.xcodeproj` file into my workspace. For now, I just have one `.swift` file, plus the header file that is generated by XCode.
My project is just called `IosUtilsTest`.

In particular, my test util file:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
  class func flexible() -> UIBarButtonItem {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
  }
}
```

And in my app:

```
import IosUtilsTest
....
toolbar.items = [UIBarButtonItem.flexible(), centeredButton, UIBarButtonItem.flexible()]
....
```

I get a compiler error that `flexible` doesn't exist.

I have tried including both `<IosUtilsTest/IosUtilsTest-swift.h>` and `<IosUtilsTest/IosUtilsTest.h>` in my bridging header.

Basically it just seems like the extension isn't being included in the build. FWIW -- I remember there was an issue with Categories requiring a special build flag, so I tried this with just a class that I tried to instantiate, and it was the same basic error.

Comment: Found an acceptable, but not ideal, workaround. Going to add the util project as a submodule, and drag the proper folder containing my swift files from Finder into my app. It will create the proper groups, etc., and should work properly such that if I update something in the util project, it updates in the workspace the next time they fetch/rebase on the submodule. Still not quite as nice as just doing a `pod install`, but I'll take it.

Comment: Swift is still undergoing **drastic** changes.  I wouldn't recommend against building static libraries in Swift until the dust settles a bit.  As it stands, in the current Xcode version, you can't even select Swift as the language for libraries (you can for everything else).  This is as clear of a sign as any that Apple is saying "Hey, you shouldn't be making Swift libraries!"

Comment: @nhgrif That's not correct. You can select Swift as the language for cocoa touch framework. Also, the warning Apple gives is regarding binaries, and especially 3rd party swift binaries that could be built with a different version of Xcode and have a different Swift runtime embedded. Your own frameworks are fine, as are 3rd parties, as long as they are all built at the same time with same Xcode. Read my answer... I'm using them and they are working fine.

Comment: @bandejapaisa are frameworks which is a different option than libraries in Xcode. I don't know exactly what the technical difference is but if you select a library and not a framework, no Swift option is given. Can you compile a framework into an independently distributable .a file?

Comment: @nhgrif A framework is basically a nicely packaged library with headers. The binary inside the framework could be a static library.

Comment: But isn't necessarily. Meanwhile, when you choose to create a STATIC LIBRARY in Xcode, which is what this question is about (not frameworks), Xcode doesn't let you pick Swift as the language.

Comment: @nhgrif, the subject is static library, but the author is 'Trying to create a utility project that is shared between my company's iOS apps'. I've provided a solution.

Comment: FWIW - @bandejapaisa is correct about my intentions. I may have used the wrong terminology in the title, but I was just looking for a way to share proprietary Swift code between projects without copy/paste. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a project comprising lots of swift framework modules that are all built together into an app, so I should be able to provide some help.

Firstly, you want to create a Cocoa Touch Framework as the project type.

The first gotcha, that got me, was that everything in the framework has to be declared public, as it is internal by default. Well, at least the parts of the API you want to expose to the clients. So use:

```
public extension UIBarButtonItem {
  class func flexible() -> UIBarButtonItem {
     return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
  }
}
```

You shouldn't need to do anymore than this, just import your module in the .swift file and also include the framework in the link binary with libraries.

We also tried cocoapods and spent quite a bit of time on it to no avail. Lots of build errors so we just gave up and used Git submodules. You're right, it's not quite as nice as cocoapod setup - but it works fine for us, just a little more overhead. You can flag your submodules as 'automatically fetch' in .gitmodules if you like.

One thing to be careful with cocoa pods if you get it working is that for the time being, all your app must be built using the same version of Xcode. So if you have a module that is built with an older version of Xcode and then put into cocoa pods, you would need to ensure you rebuild it when Xcode is updated. This is due to the swift runtime that is packaged with the build - see Apples Swift Blog for more details.

Comment: I am wondering as of xcode 8 can we convert swift project into static library ?